# How to send query result to the View?(MVC 4 & Azure Table Storage)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure

I'm new to this so bear with me please. I am building a MVC 4 application that  connects to an existing azure table storage.Right now I need to create some "filters", meaning that i must do some queries and display the result to one of the app's pages.
Right now I have the following:

Model:

```
public class psEntity : TableEntity
    {
        public psEntity() { }
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public string RoleName { get; set; }
        public string BatchName { get; set; }
        public string DeploymentID { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
```

View

```
 @model IEnumerable<MvcApplication6.Models.psEntity>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Performance Status";
}

<h2>Performance Status</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Message)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.RoleName)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Message)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RoleName)
        </td>

    </tr>
}
```

Controller:

```
public class MailingListController : Controller
    {
        public MailingListController()
        {
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
            ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["StorageConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        }

        public ActionResult Index()
        {   
            TableQuery<psEntity> query=new TableQuery<psEntity>().Where(
                TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("RoleName", 
                QueryComparisons.Equal,"Contacts.Worker.Azure"));
    foreach (psEntity list in query)
                {
                    lists.Add(list);
                }
                return View(lists);

        }
```

My question is what comes after the query, in order to show only specific data in the table I've created on the view.

I tried using foreach but got an error,

> "foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableQuery>MVCApplication6.Models.psEntity>
>   because it does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'".

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

[Retrieve all entitiesHow to: Retrieve all entities in a partition](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/table-services/)

To query a table for all entities in a partition, use a TableQuery object. The following code example specifies a filter for entities where 'Smith' is the partition key. This example prints the fields of each entity in the query results to the console.

```
// Retrieve the storage account from the connection string.
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
    CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));

// Create the table client.
CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();

// Create the CloudTable object that represents the "people" table.
CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference("people");

// Construct the query operation for all customer entities where PartitionKey="Smith".
TableQuery<CustomerEntity> query = new TableQuery<CustomerEntity>().Where(TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, "Smith"));

// Print the fields for each customer.
foreach (CustomerEntity entity in table.ExecuteQuery(query))
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}\t{2}\t{3}", entity.PartitionKey, entity.RowKey,
        entity.Email, entity.PhoneNumber);
}
```

Comment: just as I stated i already tried using foreach end ended up with the error i mentioned.